# How to subtract two rectangles?

Tags: geometry

I am wondering how to get the **Set Subtraction** between two rectangles from the programming point of view. I would really appreciate if anyone could help!

We know that in $\mathbb R^2$ each rectangle can be encoded by two points at the left-bottom and right-top corner, respectively. Now, assume that we have 2 rectangles encoded by 4 points. We observe that the set subtraction of the two rectangles is a union of some other rectangles. How can we encoded these resulting rectangles?

Of course, I can do it by considering all the possible positions of the two rectangles (there are 10 cases), but I have to do it manually and without any formula.
Are there any more efficient ways to do it?

Comment: The decomposition of the difference into rectangles is far from unique though

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Many thanks for your comment! Yes, but here we just need one of the decompositions.

Comment: If by $R_1-R_2$ you mean the set of all points of the form $x-y$ where $x\in R_1$ and $y\in R_2$, then the set subtraction of two rectangles is just a big rectangle. Indeed, this is just the two-dimensional version of the set difference of two real intervals $[a,b]-[c,d] = [a-d,b-c]$; just apply that formula to the two coordinates separately. But I guess you mean the set difference / set complement....

Comment: @GregMartin Yes many thank for your interesting observation. Here by set subtraction I mean $R_1\setminus R_2 =\{ x \in R_1 \text{ and not in } R_2\}$.

Comment: Ok, in that case there are four $x$-coordinates and four $y$-coordinates involved, which together determine a total of $4\times4=16$ subrectangles; and you can just check them one by one to see whether they are in $R_1$ and not in $R_2$.

Comment: @oh great! It is indeed the algorithmic solution that I am looking for! Just a minor comment: there are only $3\times 3=9$ sub-rectangles.

Comment: You need one more value in general to specify each rectangle, unless you are limiting to rectangles with edges that are parallel to the axes. Two diagonally opposite corners (as suggested) and then adding the angle to the other diagonal would fully specify a general oriented rectangle.

Comment: @Joffan With generally oriented rectangles, the difference would no longer be the union of finitely many rectangles

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes indeed, and could consist of up to 4 regions, with the possibility of non-convex shapes.

Answer (score 0):

*As a programming point of view is mentioned, I assume that we are only interested in lattice points (e.g., "pixels") in $\Bbb Z^2$ and need not worry about the distinction between open and closed rectangles, not to mention those containing only part of their boundary.*

Suppose you have rectangles $R_1=[x_1,x_2)\times[y_1,y_2)$ and $R_2=[x_3,x_4)\times[y_3,y_4)$, where $x_1<x_2$ etc.
To simplify, replace
$$x_3\leftarrow\max\{x_1,x_3\},\quad y_3\leftarrow\max\{y_1,y_3\},\quad
x_4\leftarrow\min\{x_2,x_4\},\quad y_4\leftarrow\min\{y_2,y_4\}.$$
This way, we make sure that $R_2$ does not extend outside $R_1$ and the following formulations become simpler insofar as we now have
$$ x_1\le x_3<x_4\le x_2,\quad y_1\le y_3<y_4\le y_2,$$
except that the above *may* make  $x_3\ge x_4$ or $y_3\ge y_4$, but then we are already done because $R_1\setminus R_2=R_1$.
Now $R_1\setminus R_2$ can be covered by four pairwise disjoint rectangle:
$$\tag1[x_1,x_3)\times[y_3,y_2)\;\cup  \;
[x_3,x_2)\times[y_4,y_2) \;\cup  \;
[x_4,x_2)\times[y_1,y_4) \;\cup  \;
[x_1,x_4)\times[y_1,y_3).$$
The only unusual thing that may happen is that one or more (in fact, perhaps all!) of these degenerate to a line (e.g., the first when $x_1=x_3$) and can thus be removed from the list.

If after removing degenerate rects, we are left with two rectangles
$$\tag2[u_1,u_2)\times [v_1,v_2)\;\cup \;[u_3,u_4)\times [v_3,v_4),$$ it *may* happen that we can simplify further if we want (but the two-rectangle partition is valid), namely

- If the horizontal intervals are the same (i.e., $u_1=u_3$ and $u_2=u_4$) and the vertical ones are juxtaposed (i.e., $v_2=v_3$ or $v_1=v_4$), thenh $(2)$ can be simplified to
  $$ [u_1,u_3)\times [\min\{v_1,v_3\},\max\{v_2,v_4\}).$$
- If the vertical intervals are the same (i.e., $v_1=v_3$ and $v_2=v_4$) and the horizontal ones are juxtaposed (i.e., $u_2=u_3$ or $u_1=u_4$), thenh $(2)$ can be simplified to
  $$ [\min\{u_1,u_3\},\max\{u_2,u_4\})\times [v_1,v_2).$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your support! But I have to admit that the strategy it is not very clear for me. The assumption *$R_2$  does not extend outside $R_1$* does not hold in general. In general, $R_2$ can be subset of $R_1$, it can have empty intersection, non-empty intersection and it may even contain $R_1$.